# Commerce doesn't handle Sagepay Form Integration return

Tags: 7, commerce

So I'm using SagePay Form Integration on my site, but it has ceased to function correctly.

So on the Payment Stage of Checkout it says 'Use the button below to proceed to the payment server.'. Now I successfully complete a payment on the Sage Pay Testing Server and it comes back to the site URL checkout/order_id/payment/return attached with some GET vars.

The issue is that when it returns, checkout just displays 'Use the button below to proceed to the payment server.' again. The status of the order hasn't been updated and the user isn't ushered to the complete stage. Any idea why this is?

After further inspection it also seems that under Store > Orders it isn't logging the payment as it had previous. The order just remains at the payment stage in 'Shopping Carts'
tab of Admin > Store > Orders.

I'm having this exact same issue with all of the following versions:

- 7.x-1.0-beta2
- 7.x-1.0-beta1
- 7.x-1.x-dev

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Firebug Lite script in `html.tpl.php` was causing the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

Swiftly removed.